# Read Only Multitable DTO + Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, dto, subquery, multi-table

I have two tables in my DB, T1 and T2. One column of T1 is a foreign key that references T2. I need only a part of the columns of T1 and T2 for my processing, thus I've created a DTO T1T2 that contains only the necessary columns. To map the DTO to these two tables with Hibernate, I used subselect attribute of the class element.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class
    name="com.xconnect.cdrrecorder.processing.dto.IngressNumRuleVoipProfile"
    table="numbermodificationrules"
    subselect="select ... from T1 left join T2 on id1=id2 where ...">

    <cache usage="read-only"/>

...

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I noticed that when i need to select for an object, Hibernate converts the request to two selects (one into the other).

Is there a better way to do this? What do you think about performances?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a DTO, better to fill the DTO from the query as in an example [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/09/hibernate-data-fetching-options.html). Only create the entity if there are backing  tables.

If the DTO is used very often you can write a view in the DB and create a simple DTO entity to  refer that. Since view is pre-compiled in the DB, it will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html) (section 5.1.1), the use of subselect is explained. My question is in which cases we need to use subselect instead of other ways for querying?

Comment: As told in the link, _Sometimes you want to use a view, but you cannot create one in the database (i.e. with a legacy schema). In this case, you can map an immutable and read-only entity to a given SQL subselect expression_. If you can, go with the view.